# Populate Listboxes using RPC in UiBinder in GWT

Tags: gwt, listbox, uibinder

I am trying to populate a dropdown from database using Rpc (Async). The problem is that on the page load, the dropdown does not get populated. I am trying to create this in UIBinder but I cannot find any suitable handler to populate dropboxes on page load.

Comment: I just realized that I was trying to make calls on the widget instead of the onload. I used the OnLoad method in uibinder java class and that helped me populate the values in listbox on the page load. Hope this helps people who are stuck like me.

Comment: You **can** post an [answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :) It's even encouraged, especially in a case like this.